# How are CQ5 blog entries saved in JCR?

Tags: aem

I am using a CQ5 social blog page. I can see the new entries are saved in the /social`/blog/components/entryform`
using this form element

```
<form action= "<this page>.social.createblogentry.html" />
```

I need to know how this form works and how does it save the Blog entry using this component as a supertype

```
/social/blog/components/entrytext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise taking a look at Apache Sling, outside of CQ5.

If you follow the steps through "Discover Sling in 15 Minutes", you will get a good idea for how content is stored.

They also have a guide on how to create a Blog.

Discover Sling in 15 Minutes: http://sling.apache.org/documentation/getting-started/discover-sling-in-15-minutes.html

Blog Tutorial: http://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/46-line-blog.html

I think you'll get much more value out of performing these tutorials manually, to see how the content forms in a structure, versus reading a one-two paragraph explanation.